# Parsing simple name/value pair settings in config file with leading and terminating spaces - C

Tags: c, file, parsing, configuration, spaces

This is the code I made so far. I apologize if my buffer sizes are an overkill.

The idea is to read the entire configuration file (in this example, it's `file.conf`), and for now we assume it exists. I'll add error checking later.

Once the file is read into stack space, then the `getcfg()` function searches the configuration data for the specified name, and if it's found, returns the corresponding value.  My function works when the configuration file contains leading spaces before names or values; such spaces are ignored.

Say this is my configuration file:

```
something=data
apples=oranges
fruit=banana
      animals=       cats
fried    =chicken
```

My code will work correctly with the first four entries of the config file. for example, if I use "something" as the name, then "data" will be returned.

The last item won't work as of yet because of the trailing spaces after "fried" and before the `=`. I want to be able to have my function automatically remove those spaces, too, especially in case an option format such as

```
somethingelse = items
```

begins to be used.  (Note the spaces on both sides of the `=` sign.)

What can I do to make a less CPU-intensive version of my program that also detects and removes trailing spaces from the name and value when processing the name and values?

Here's my current code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getcfg(char* buf, char *name, char *val) {
    int fl = 0, n = 0;
    char cfg[1][10000], *p = buf;

    memset(cfg, 0, sizeof(cfg));
    while (*p) {
        if (*p == '\n') {
            if (strcmp(cfg[0], name) == 0) {
                strcpy(val, cfg[1]);
                return 1;
            }
            memset(cfg, 0, sizeof(cfg));
            n = 0;
            fl = 0;
        } else {
            if (*p == '=') {
                n = 0;
                fl = 1;
            } else {
                if (n != 0 || *p != ' ') {
                    cfg[fl][n] = *p;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char val[10000], buf[100000]; //val=value of config item, buf=buffer for entire config file ( > 100KB config file is nuts)

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    memset(val, 0, sizeof(val));

    int h = open("file.conf", O_RDONLY);

    if (read(h, buf, sizeof(buf)) < 1) {
        printf("Can't read\n");
    }
    close(h);

    printf("Value stat = %d ", getcfg(buf, "Item", val));
    printf("Result = '%s'\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `fgets` to read a line at a time and `strtok` to help you parse the key/value pair. `strtok` will easily solve the extra white space problems for you.

Comment: Everyone seems to love strtok but it doesn't work well with 64-bit systems as the string pointer gets messed up when passed in. Also, fgets works with file handles of type FILE*, not of type int. I'm using open because I want an unbuffered read of the config file since I could change it between the time I finished testing the program and the time I test it again.

Comment: "Everyone seems to love strtok but it doesn't work well with 64-bit systems as the string pointer gets messed up when passed in.". That doesn't sound right at all. Are you sure you haven't got mixed up 32 and 64 bit libraries? If it appears a standard library doesn't work in your code then I think you should start with the assumption that something is wrong on your end and not the standard library.

Comment: @Mike, `strtok()` works just fine on 64-bit systems.  If you find otherwise then either your program is wrong (most likely) or your C library is broken (highly unlikely).  C does not allow implementations to break as you assert.

Comment: "make a less CPU-intensive version"  -->  My money is that all the I/O activity swamps any parsing issues.  Use `fgets()` and then parse sensible.

Comment: Try this: http://criticalindirection.com/2016/01/05/lex-based-config-parserreader/

Answer (score 3):

Behold is a small (~15 lines) sscanf-based read_params() function which does the job. As a bonus, it understands the comments and complains about erroneous lines (if any):

```
$ cat config_file.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) ((sizeof (a)) / (sizeof (a)[0]))

enum { MAX_LEN=128 };

struct param {
    char name[MAX_LEN];
    char value[MAX_LEN];
};

void strtrim(char *s)
{
    char *p = s + strlen(s);

    while (--p >= s && isspace(*p))
        *p = '\0';
}

int read_params(FILE *in, struct param *p, int max_params)
{
    int ln, n=0;
    char s[MAX_LEN];

    for (ln=1; max_params > 0 && fgets(s, MAX_LEN, in); ln++) {
        if (sscanf(s, " %[#\n\r]", p->name)) /* emty line or comment */
            continue;
        if (sscanf(s, " %[a-z_A-Z0-9] = %[^#\n\r]",
                   p->name, p->value) < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error at line %d: %s\n", ln, s);
            return -1;
        }
        strtrim(p->value);
        printf("%d: name='%s' value='%s'\n", ln, p->name, p->value);
        p++, max_params--, n++;
    }

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    struct param p[32];

    f = argc == 1 ? stdin : fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open `%s': %s\n", argv[1],
            strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (read_params(f, p, ARRAY_SIZE(p)) < 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Let's see how it works (quotes mark the beginning and the end of each line for clarity):

```
$ cat bb | sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" | cat -n
     1  'msg = Hello World! '
     2  'p1=v1'
     3  ' p2=v2 # comment'
     4  ' '
     5  'P_3 =v3'
     6  'p4= v4#comment'
     7  ' P5 = v5 '
     8  '   # comment'
     9  'p6 ='
$ ./config_file bb
1: name='msg' value='Hello World!'
2: name='p1' value='v1'
3: name='p2' value='v2'
5: name='P_3' value='v3'
6: name='p4' value='v4'
7: name='P5' value='v5'
error at line 9: p6 =
```

Note: as an additional bonus, the value can be anything, except `#\n\r` chars, including spaces, as can be seen above with the 'Hello World!' example. If it's not what needed, add space and tab into the exception list at the second sscanf() for the value (or specify accepted characters there instead) and drop strtrim() function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a straight-forward version, with everything being done in `main` and no `key:value` *saving* - the function only recognizes where they are and print them. I used the input file you gave and added one more line in the end as `something = more_data`.

This version of the parser **does not** recognize multiple data itens (itens separated by spaces in the data fields, you'll have to figure it out as an exercise).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("file.conf", O_RDONLY, 0);
    int i = 0;
    char kv[100];
    char c;

    while (read(fd,&c,1) == 1) {
        /* ignoring spaces and tabs */
        if (c == '\t' || c == ' ') continue;
        else if (c == '=') {
            /* finished reading a key */
            kv[i] = 0x0;
            printf("key found [%s] ", kv);
            i = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            /* finished reading a value */
            kv[i] = 0x0;
            printf(" with data [%s]\n", kv);
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }
        kv[i++] = c;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
key found [something]  with data [data]
key found [apples]  with data [oranges]
key found [fruit]  with data [banana]
key found [animals]  with data [cats]
key found [fried]  with data [chicken]
key found [something]  with data [more_data]
```

---

### Explanation

1. **`while (read(fd,&c,1) == 1)`**: reads one character at a time from the file.
2. **`if (c == '\t' || c == ' ') continue;`**: this is responsible for ignoring the white-spaces and tabs wherever they are.
3. **`else if (c == '=')`**: If the program finds a `=` character, it concludes that what it just read was a key and treats it. What's inside that `if` should be easy to understand.
4. **`else if (c == '\n')`**: Then it uses a new-line character to recognize the end of a value. Again, what's inside the `if` is not hard to understand.
5. **`kv[i++] = c;`**: This is where we save the char value into the buffer `kv`.

---

So, with some minor changes, you can adapt this bit of code to become a parsing function that will suit your needs.

---

### Edit and new code

As pointed out by [John Bollinger](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html) in the comments, using `read` inside a `while` to read one character at a time is very costly. I'll post a second version of the program using the same input method OP was using (reading the whole file at once into a buffer) and then parsing it with another function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void parse(char *s)
{
    char c, kv[100];
    int i;
    while ((c = *s++)) {
        /* ignoring spaces and tabs */
        if (c == '\t' || c == ' ') continue;
        else if (c == '=') {
            /* finished reading a key */
            kv[i] = 0x0;
            printf("key found [%s] ", kv);
            i = 0;
            continue;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            /* finished reading a value */
            kv[i] = 0x0;
            printf(" with data [%s]\n", kv);
            i = 0;
            continue;
        }
        kv[i++] = c;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("file.conf", O_RDONLY, 0);
    char buffer[1000];

    /* use the reading method that suits you best */
    read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);

    /* only thing parse() expects is a null-terminated string */
    parse(buffer);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `read` sets `c` to `0` at the end of file?

Comment: @user58697 That's true, don't know where I got that from. I'll edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you're going to read one `char` at a time, then it would be better to use `fgetc()`, which is likely to buffer the input stream.  Using `read()` to input the whole file one byte at a time is likely to be costly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with you. But this is just a way of showing how the _parsing method_ works. OP was reading the whole file at once, and when he converts this bit of code into a function, he may just use `while(*s)` instead of the `read` thing. Do you think it's worthing pointing that out in the answer (for completeness)? Or even changing the code?

Comment: @EnzoFerber, the OP did express a performance concern, and you could switch from `read()` to `fgetc()` without many other changes.  I do, therefore, think it worthwhile to present the `fgetc()` variation on your method.  Or alternatively, buffer-at-a-time I/O and in-memory parsing.  Or at that point, why not just `mmap()` the config file?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added a buffer parsing function. That way, OP can decide which input method he wants. The only thing the `parse` function now expects is a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual to read a whole config file into memory as a flat image, and especially to *keep* such an image as the internal representation.  One would ordinarily parse the file contents into key/value pairs as you go, and store a representation of those pairs.

Also, your use of `read()` is incorrect, as you cannot safely assume that it will read all bytes of the file in one call.  One normally must call `read()` in a loop, keeping track of the return value from each call to know both when the end of the file is reached and where in the buffer to put the next bytes read.

If the configuration is supposed to be completely generic, so that you don't know in advance what keywords to expect, then you might organize the configuration data in a hash table or a binary search tree, with the parameter names as the keys.  If you *do* know what parameters to expect (or at least which to allow), then you might have a variable or a struct member for each one.

Naturally, the approach to parameter lookup must be paired correctly with the data structure in which you store the parameters.  Any of the approaches I suggested will make looking up multiple configuration parameters far faster.  They would also avoid wasting memory, and would adapt to extremely large configurations (or at least *could* do so).

How best to approach reading the file depends on details of your config file format, such as whether keys and/or values are permitted to contain internal spaces, whether more than one key/value pair may appear on the same line, and whether there is an upper bound on the allowed length of config file lines or of keys and values.  Here's an approach that expects one key/value pair per line, supports keys and values that contain internal whitespace (but not newlines), but neither of which is longer than 1023 characters, and where keys are not permitted to contain the `'='` character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    char key[1024];
    char value[1024];
    FILE *config;
    int done;

    config = fopen("file.conf", "r");
    if (!config) {
        perror("while opening file.conf");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        char nl = '\0';
        int nfields = fscanf(config, " %1023[^=\n]= %1023[^\n]%c", key, value, &nl);
        int i;

        done = 1;

        if (nfields == EOF) {
            if (ferror(config)) {
                /* handle read error ... */
                perror("while reading file.conf");
            } else {
                /* trailing empty line(s); ignore ... */
            }
            break;
        } else if (nfields == 3) {
            if (nl != '\n') {
                /* handle excessive-length value ... */
            } else {
                done = 0;
            }
        } else if (nfields == 1) {
            /* handle excessive-length key ... */
            break;
        } else {
            assert(nfields == 2);
            /* last key/value pair, not followed by a newline */
        }

        if (key[0] == '=') {
            /* handle missing key ... */
            break;
        }

        /* successfully read a key / value pair; truncate trailing whitespace */
        for (i = strlen(key); key[--i] == ' '; ) {
            /* nothing */
        }
        key[i + 1] ='\0';
        for (i = strlen(value); value[--i] == ' '; ) {
            /* nothing */
        }
        value[i + 1] ='\0';

        /* record the key / value pair somewhere (but here we just print it) ... */
        printf("key: [%s]   value: [%s]\n", key, value);
    } while (!done);

    fclose(config);

    return 0;
}
```

Important points to note about that include:

- No mechanism for *storing* the key / value pairs is provided.  I gave you a few options, and there are others, but you must decide what's best for your own purposes.  Rather, the program above addresses the problem of parsing your config data once for all, so that you can avoid parsing it *de novo* every time you perform a lookup.
- The code relies on `fscanf()` to consume any leading whitespace before the key and value, but in order to accommodate internal whitespace in the key and value, it cannot do the same for trailing whitespace.
- Instead, it manually trims trailing whitespace from key and value.
- The `fscanf()` format uses explicit field widths to avoid buffer overruns.  It uses the `%[` and `%c` field descriptors to scan data that may be or include whitespace.
- Although it may look longish, do note how much of that code is dedicated to error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer.

Getting the data and parsing it are best handled with 2 separate routines.

1) Use `fgets()` or other code with `read()` to read a *line*

```
int foo(FILE *inf) {
  char buffer[1000];
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, inf)) {
    if (Parse_KeyValue(buffer, &key_offset, &value_offset)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad Line '%s'\n", buffer);
      return 1;
    }
    printf("'%s'='%s'\n", &buffer[key_offset], &buffer[value_offset]);
  }
}
```

2) Parse the line. (Sample unchecked code)

```
// 0: Success
// 1: failure
int Parse_KeyValue(char *line, size_t *key_offset, size_t *value_offset) {
  char *p = line;
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;
  *key_offset = p - line;
  const char *end = p;
  while (*p != '=') {
    if (*p == '\0') return 1;  // fail, no `=` found
    if (!isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
      end = p+1;
    }
    p++;
  }
  *end = '\0';

  p++; // consume `=`    
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;
  *value_offset = p - line;
  end = p;
  while (*p) {
    if (!isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
      end = p+1;
    }
    p++;
  }
  *end = '\0';
  return 0;
}
```

This does allow for valid `""` key and value.  Adjust as needed.