# C code to read config file and parse directives

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a config file and parse the config directives. So far I have the following code, I need advice on how to improve this or change it. Is this efficient? Thanks!

```
struct config
{
    char host;
    char port;
}

void parse_line(char *buf) {
    char *line;
    if(strstr(buf, "host=") || strstr(buf, "host = ") || strstr(buf, "host= ") || strstr(buf, "host =")) {
        line = strstr(buf, "=");
        printf("Host: %s", &line[2]);
    } else if(strstr(buf, "port=") || strstr(buf, "port = ") || strstr(buf, "port= ") || strstr(buf, "port =")) {
        line = strstr(buf, "=");
        printf("Port: %s", &line[2]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *file_name;
    FILE *file;
    file_name = argv[1];
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    // check if file is NULL, etc..

    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char *line;
    int i;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) { // iterate through the chars in a line
            if(buffer[i] == '#') { // if char is a #, stop processing chars on this line
                break;
            } else if(buffer[i] == ' ') { // if char is whitespace, continue until something is found
                continue;
            } else {
                parse_line(buffer); // if char is not a # and not whitespace, it is a config directive, parse it
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a way to ignore `#` if it is a first character on a line, and also lines that are white spaces. I think my code does that, but is that efficient?

**EDIT:**

Thanks everyone for all the suggestions, I have managed to do this simple code to trim the white spaces, so that I wouldn't need all the `strstr()` calls.

```
void trim(char *src)
{
    int i, len;
    len = strlen(src);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(src[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        if(src[i] == '\n' || src[i] == '#') {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c", src[i]); // prints: host=1.2.3.4
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "host =  1.2.3.4 # this is a comment\n";
    trim(str);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It prints correctly: `host=1.2.3.4` but now I need this in a variable to be further parsed. I think I will try to use `strcpy`.

**EDIT 2:**

I do not think that `strcpy` is the right choice. Those chars are printed out in a loop, so every time I use `strcpy`, the previous char is overwritten. I have tried this, but it does not work because only the `host=` part is placed into arr. The IP part is not placed into `arr`.. how can this be fixed..

```
char arr[sizeof(src)];

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(src[i] == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    if(src[i] == '\n' || src[i] == '#') {
        break;
    }
    printf("%c", src[i]); // prints: host=1.2.3.4
    arr[i] = src[i];
}

int j;
for(j = 0; j < sizeof(arr); j++) {
    printf("%c", arr[j]); //prints: host=
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

I found the correct way of placing chars into `arr`:

```
int i, count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(src[i] == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    if(src[i] == '\n' || src[i] == '#') {
        break;
    }
    arr[count] = src[i];
    count++;
}
```

Comment: If you have working code and are just looking for ways to improve it, you should be asking on [codereview.se] instead. This site is for questions about problems with code or a programming tool. [codereview.se] was created specifically for those asking for peer review for advice related to working code.

Comment: Is this for parsing an `ssh` config file? In `parse_line`, why not just check the first word as `host` or `port` with `strncmp` and then locate the `=` with `strchr` and find the first char following the pointer returned that isn't `isspace`? That seems a more systematic way or finding `host/port` and the values that follow. For the `port` line, an option is to just call `strtol` on one past the pointer returned by `strchr` and `=`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing simple name/value pair settings in config file with leading and terminating spaces - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268023/parsing-simple-name-value-pair-settings-in-config-file-with-leading-and-terminat)

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation is pretty fragile. Parsers really ought to verify syntax and return errors when they see something unexpected. For example, yours should detect missing fields and multiply defined ones.

Fortunately this parsing problem is simple enough for `sscanf` to handle everything:

- skip blank lines,
- skip comments
- ignore any amount of whitespace
- extract the key/value pairs

Here's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONFIG_SIZE (256)
#define HOST_SET (1)
#define PORT_SET (2)

typedef struct config {
  unsigned set;
  char host[CONFIG_SIZE];
  unsigned long port;
} CONFIG;

// Parse the buffer for config info. Return an error code or 0 for no error.
int parse_config(char *buf, CONFIG *config) {
  char dummy[CONFIG_SIZE];
  if (sscanf(buf, " %s", dummy) == EOF) return 0; // blank line
  if (sscanf(buf, " %[#]", dummy) == 1) return 0; // comment
  if (sscanf(buf, " host = %s", config->host) == 1) {
    if (config->set & HOST_SET) return HOST_SET; // error; host already set
    config->set |= HOST_SET;
    return 0;
  }
  if (sscanf(buf, " port = %lu", &config->port) == 1) {
    if (config->set & PORT_SET) return PORT_SET; // error; port already set
    config->set |= PORT_SET;
    return 0;
  }
  return 3; // syntax error
}

void init_config(CONFIG *config) {
  config->set = 0u;
}

void print_config(CONFIG *config) {
  printf("[host=%s,port=", config->set & HOST_SET ? config->host : "<unset>");
  if (config->set & PORT_SET) printf("%lu]", config->port); else printf("<unset>]");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s CONFIG_FILE\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char buf[CONFIG_SIZE];
  CONFIG config[1];
  init_config(config);
  int line_number = 0;
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)) {
    ++line_number;
    int err = parse_config(buf, config);
    if (err) fprintf(stderr, "error line %d: %d\n", line_number, err);
  }
  print_config(config);
  return 0;
}
```

With this input:

```
# This is a comment

This isn't
   # Non-leading comment
host = 123.456.789.10

 ###
port =42

port=    1
host=fruit.foo.bar
```

the output is

```
error line 3: 3
error line 10: 2
error line 11: 1
[host=fruit.foo.bar,port=1]
```

Note that when the parser discovers a field has already been set, it still uses the latest value in the config. It's easy enough to keep the original instead. I'll let you have that fun.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can improve performance:

1. Calling strstr() in this scenario is inefficient, because the presence of the "host" part of buf can be checked once instead of multiple times every time strstr() is called. Instead, make an if statement that checks if buf begins with "host", then check if buf contains the other elements. The same thing applies to the portion of code checking for the presence of "port".
2. In the loop in main, instead of doing this:

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) { // iterate through the chars in a line
   if(buffer[i] == '#') { // if char is a #, stop processing chars on this line
       break;
   } else if(buffer[i] == ' ') { // if char is whitespace, continue until something is found
       continue;
   } else {
       parse_line(buffer); // if char is not a # and not whitespace, it is a config directive, parse it
       break;
   }
   ```

do this:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) { // iterate through the chars in a line
    char temp = buffer[i];
    if(temp == '#') { // if char is a #, stop processing chars on this line
        break;
    } else if (temp != ' ') {
        parse_line(buffer); // if char is not a # and not whitespace, it is a config directive, parse it
        break;
    }
```

Checking to see if something is not equal to another is likely to be just as fast as checking if they are equal (at least on Intel, the je (jump equal) and jne (jump not equal) instructions exhibit the same latency of 1 cycle each), so the statement with the continue in it is not necessary. The temp variable is so that buffer[i] does not need to be calculated in the second if again in case the first if is false. Also, do what user3121023 stated below (same reason for performance as creating the temp variable).

3. You can use operating-system-specific functions (such as thos from the library WINAPI/WIN32/WIN64 (synonyms) on windows) instead of C standard library functions. Microsoft has very good documentation about their functions in the MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) web site.
4. Use `uint_fast8_t` (defined in stdint.h, this typedef is set to the fastest integer type greater than or equal to the size in bits specified in the typedef) when performing operations on the host and port (but use chars when storing the variables on the disk, in order to make read i/o operations faster).
5. This isn't related to performance , but use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` in main instead of `return 0;`, since using EXIT_SUCCESS is more readable and exhibits the same performance.

Comment: And all this comes to not because you end of waiting on File IO.  Please profile a release build before even thinking about performance.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Even though the performance gains are negligible in relation to the cost of io, this isn't hard to implement and the loop was made more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think `parse_line` is a little bit rigid for my taste, I would use `strtok`
instead. Then you don't have to worry too much about spaces, like you do if you
have a space before the `=` sign.

Your `struct` is also wrong, `host` and `port` would only hold a character.
Besides `port` should be an integer. And you need a semicolon `;` after the
struct definition.

```
struct config
{
  char host[100];
  int port;
};

int parse_line(struct config *config, char *buf)
{
    if(config == NULL || buf == NULL)
        return 0;

    char varname[100];
    char value[100];
    const char* sep = "=\n"; // get also rid of newlines
    char *token;

    token = strtok(buf, sep);

    strncpy(varname, token, sizeof varname);
    varname[sizeof(varname) - 1] = 0; // making sure that varname is C-String

    trim(varname);

    token = strtok(NULL, sep);

    if(token == NULL)
    {
        // line not in format var=val
        return 0;
    }

    strncpy(value, token, sizeof value);
    value[sizeof(varname) - 1] = 0

    trim(value);

    if(strcmp(varname, "port") == 0)
    {
        config->port = atoi(value);
        return 1;
    }


    if(strcmp(varname, "host") == 0)
    {
        strncpy(config->host, value, siezof config->host);
        config->host[(sizeof config->host) - 1] = 0;
        return 1;
    }


    // var=val not recognized
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I used a function called `trim`. This function is not part of the
standard library. Below I posted a possible implementation of such a function.

I like using `trim` because it gets rid of white spaces. Now you can do this in
`main`:

```
struct config config;
// initializing
config.port = 0;
config.host[0] = 0;

int linecnt = 0;

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
    linecnt++;
    trim(buffer);
    if(buffer[0] == '#')
        continue;

    if(!parse_line(&config, buffer))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error on line %d, ignoring.\n", linecnt);
        continue;
    }
}
```

---

A possible implementation of `trim`

```
void rtrim(char *src)
{
    size_t i, len;
    volatile int isblank = 1;

    if(src == NULL) return;

    len = strlen(src);
    if(len == 0) return;
    for(i = len - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {   
        isblank = isspace(src[i]);
        if(isblank)
            src[i] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }   
    if(isspace(src[i]))
        src[i] = 0;
}

void ltrim(char *src)
{
    size_t i, len;

    if(src == NULL) return;

    i = 0;
    len = strlen(src);
    if(len == 0) return;
    while(src[i] && isspace(src[i]))
                i++;

    memmove(src, src + i, len - i + 1); 
    return;
}

void trim(char *src)
{
    rtrim(src);
    ltrim(src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I can't help but wonder if rolling your own parser is so great.

Why not use an existing JSON or YAML parser and test for keys in the parsed data?

This will be easily extendible by allowing for new keys to be added with very little effort and the common format of the configuration file makes it very easy for developers to edit.

If you are going to roll out your own parser, than some of the previously mentioned advice makes a lot of sense.

The biggest ones are: **don't seek the whole buffer**, read the single line that's in front of you and **report any errors**. Also, **advance as you go**.

Your parser should work correctly if someone would dump a GigaByte of garbage into the configuration file, so make no assumptions about the data.